# PHP: DOMNode::appendChild to an array of Elements

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, appendchild, domexception

I am using DOMDocument to parse an XML file. I loop through the different Elements and see if any of them is missing and I fill an array with a createElement, with the error message. At the end I'm trying to appendChild that array but I always get the same error message:

```
Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Wrong Document Error'
DOMNode->appendChild(Object(DOMElement))
1 {main}
thrown in /xxx/xxx.php on line 235
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::item() in /xxx/xxx.php on line 235.
```

the code is as follow:

```
$SMQuery = new DOMDocument();
$SMQuery->loadXML($params);
$response = $SMQuery->createElement('SMreply');
$errors = array();
if (!$reqtyp = $SMQuery->getElementsByTagName("tag1"))
{$errors[] = $SMQuery->createElement('error', 'tag1 Element is missing');}
if (!$reqtyp = $SMQuery->getElementsByTagName("tag2"))
{$errors[] = $SMQuery->createElement('error', 'tag2 Element is missing');}
......

if(!empty($errors))
{
 foreach($errors as $error) {
  $response->appendChild($error); <==== this line is causing the error !!!
 }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Cheers,
Riki.

Comment: GOT IT!!!! I had a typo in my original code!

Comment: So what was the typo and the correction?

Answer (score 2):

You don't show where `$response` is being defined, but if it's the result of another `new DOMDocument()`, then that explains you error - you can't add nodes from one DOM object to another directly. It has to be imported first via [`->importNode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php). Only after that can you actually append it.

Comment: Sorry that line was missing. $response is defined (I just edited the code there and added it)!. ->importNode causes the same error message. I don't think I need to do an importNode, because if I do 
    $test = $SMQuery->createElement('test','test');
    $response->appendChild($test);
that works fine, and do not need to use importNode!